# Using jquery ajax post to submit a POST request in Phoenix Framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, elixir, phoenix-framework

We want to use our content editable, taking advantage of the generated routes with the following in router.ex:

```
  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end
  scope "/", TextEditor do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    resources "/posts", PostController
  end
```

and the controller functions, namely create:

```
  def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
    changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{}, post_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _post} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Post created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: post_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

However we don't want to use the generated form, we are then attempting to test this with divs and the jquery method $.post:

```
<div id="newPost" contenteditable="true">write here</div>
<div id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var post = $("#newPost").html();

    $.post( "/posts/post", { title: post })
     .done(function() {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " );
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

However we are not getting the alert or any data inserted into our database.
What are we missing?

EDIT: In the browser pipeline we removed the cross forgery plug because of a csrf token error.

Comment: Do you get any error in your console? Could you please post your `browser` pipeline?

Comment: No errors. In the console we get: ```[info] POST /posts/post```.

I added the browser pipeline to the question. We removed the cross forgery plug because of the csrf token error.

Comment: Not that you should do this as a solution, but could you check if it works if you remove `:put_secure_browser_headers`?

Comment: I tested and it does not work by removing it.

Comment: We also had a problem with params which is why we added "post" to "/posts/" ("/posts/post").

Comment: That is incorrect. You should post to `/posts` - otherwise the route will not match. I am surprised it does not 404 when you post to `/posts/post`. What is the error you get when it is `POST /posts`?

Comment: It is: ```(Phoenix.MissingParamError) expected key "post" to be present in params, please send the expected key or adapt your scrub_params/2 call```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863118/phoenix-csrf-token-not-matching/49745172

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$.post( "/posts", { post: { title: post } })
```

Your controller expects the parameters to be nested under a key of `post`

```
def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
```

I wouldn't recommend doing so, but you can change your controller to:

```
def create(conn, %{} = post_params) do
```

To look for parameters without the root `post` key. However having the `post` key means you can have additional parameters unrelated to the form easily.

I also would not recomment disabling the CSRF check. You can submit with the CSRF token easily by storing it in a meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf" content="<%= Plug.CSRFProtection.get_csrf_token() %>">
```

And then adding it as a header to your post request:

```
var csrf = document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf]").content;

$.ajax({
    url: "/posts",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      post: { title: post } })
    },
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf 
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works but the csrf token didn't. If I keep it removed from the pipeline, it works.

Comment: I have managed to make PUT requests (updates) using the above mentioned code but the problem is that I get `session not fetched` error when I try (in my controller's update function) to get the id of the currently logged in user (the one who makes the jQuery AJAX calls). I need the user id in order to restrict the user's ability to update only the entities associated with his user_id.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to pass that in? @W.M.